# pywin32 excel find how many sheets are in a workbook and index by number?

Tags: python, excel, pywin32

How do I find the number of sheets in a workbook in pywin32?

Also, is there ANY documentation on how to use pywin32 with excel? I can't seem to even find code examples or anything.

Comment: Google for *python com excel* and you'll find examples.  If you just need to extract data from excel, search for `xlrd` or `openpyxl`.

Comment: i tried xlrd, but it dosen't work for xlsx files

Comment: I also need to write data to the excel file while reading it

Comment: `openpyxl` reads and writes xlsx files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch

xl= Dispatch("Excel.Application")
xl.Visible = True # otherwise excel is hidden

# newest excel does not accept forward slash in path
wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(r'U:\Example.xls')
print "count of sheets:", wb.Sheets.Count
for sh in wb.Sheets:
    print sh.Name
wb.Close()
xl.Quit()
```

Result:

```
count of sheets: 3
Sheet1
Sheet2
Sheet3
```

Your best documentation is found provided with Excel.  Generally, I record a macro, look at the generated code, learn from the help file, and write what I need in Python.